# How should I structure my codeigniter controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

**PROBLEM AT HAND:**

I am creating a "micro web site" with no more than 10 pages.  The login form is on the home page when a user isn't signed in.  Here is a quick break down.

Public Access Pages:

- Home Page (non-member)
- Info Page
- News Page
- Registration Page

Member Access Pages:

- Home Page (member version)
- My Account Page
- Enter Contest Page

**Potential Solution:**

I am not sure the best solution for my controllers.  I was thinking of using 2 controllers, a public controller, and a member controller.  My default controller would be public.  The constructor will check if a user is logged in, and if they are, redirect them to the member controller:

```
redirect('member')
```

The member page will be loaded, which has a few more links than the public page.  And when a use clicks to enter contest, the member constructor makes sure they are logged in, and then shows the contest view.

Is this how it should be done to have privileged access.  I will also add an admin page for the administrator to change the prizes.  So there will be 3 privileges.

Thanks!

Comment: For such a small project you can use something like Drupal and Wordpress

Comment: @David I was pretty interested in codeigniter when I started and would like to see it through.  I'll look into Drupal and WOrdpress in future small projects

Comment: I think what i needed to google was codeigniter privilege control :)  getting somewhere now

Answer (score 1):

You did great to name all of your view files there.  Now, other than the 2 home views, you can create a controller for each of those views and a model for the controllers that need access to a database.

In the construct for each of your privileged controllers, check the person's access level.  If they don't have access for those pages, redirect them somewhere else or possibly load a view with an error message.

With the home view, it's the same except you are just deciding whether to load the non-member or member home page depending on whether they are logged in or not.  I.e. you don't really need a redirect on failure.

Comment: I think I get where you are going.  Now I'm starting to wonder if I should have 2 different home pages, or just draw the enter contest and my account links based on their privileges.  But then My view would need to check a sessions which kind of screws with MVC correct?

Comment: Well, it's totally OK to have 2 alternative view files if they are that different.  Also, keep in mind you can load sections of view files.  I.e. Load the header, a side col, pick from what links view you want to load, etc. down to the footer.  Otherwise, Save the account links or whatever to an array and pass $data['links'] (or whatever) to the view.  Just use a foreach (or the parser) to output in the view.